# When Python circular import is unavoidable, what is the best solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, circular-dependency

I first ran into this problem in the context of a larger set of existing libraries which are in serious need of a reorganisation. However, now is not the time and a problem has arisen after a recent set of changes. I've created an abstract example, which has the exact same problem as the real libraries.

We have the following file structure:

```
|- pack
|  |- sub_a
|  |  |- __init__.py
|  |  |- a_func.py
|  |- sub_b
|  |  |- __init__.py
|  |  |- b_func.py
|  |- __init__.py
|- runit.py
```

The main program is `runit.py`, it imports specific stuff it wants from the `pack` package and runs it.

`runit.py`:

```
import pack

print(pack.fa())
print(pack.fb())
print(pack.fab())
print(pack.fba())
```

The pack package consists of the rest of the files, starting with `pack\__init__.py`:

```
from .sub_a import fa, fab
from .sub_b import fb, fba
```

`pack\sub_a\__init__.py`:

```
from .a_func import fa, fab
```

`pack\sub_a\a_func.py`:

```
from ..sub_b import fb


def fa():
    return 0


def fab():
    return fb()
```

`pack\sub_b\__init__.py`:

```
from .b_func import fb, fba
```

`pack\sub_b\b_func.py`:

```
from ..sub_a import fa


def fb():
    return 1


def fba():
    return fa()
```

Now here is the problem: if you try to run runit.py, it fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/adir/runit.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pack
  File "C:\adir\pack\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .sub_a import fa, fab
  File "C:\adir\pack\sub_a\a_func.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..sub_b import fb
  File "C:\adir\pack\sub_b\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .b_func import fb, fba
  File "C:\adir\pack\sub_b\b_func.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..sub_a import fa
ImportError: cannot import name 'fb' 'fa' from 'pack.sub_a' (C:\adir\pack\sub_a\__init__.py)
```

However, if you remove the `fa` import (and change the line using it in `fba()`), it does work, in spite of the identical import of `fb` in `a_func.py`.

The cause is the fact that `sub_a` needs something from `sub_b`, but `sub_b` needs something from `sub_a`, so what is created is a circular import.

Now, of course for this example, the circular import is silly. The easiest solution would be to put all the functions in one place; then, since there is no circular dependency between the functions, there is no problem.

But for the actual situation, there is good reason for the somewhat circular reference (I say 'somewhat' because there is no actual circular dependency of functions, but of course Python doesn't know that until run-time).

The only options I see:

1. put everything in one place;
2. refactor the modules so that the code that is required by all others sits in a separate module, which does not depend on the rest; in this example, that would be `fa()` and/or `fb()`;
3. move the import statement to where it is needed, instead of at the top; in this example it would move inside of the `fba()` definition;
4. refactor the actual functions / classes to rely on dependency injection; in this example, `fba()` could have a `callback` parameter;
5. add an initialisation method for the module.

I don't like the first four: option 1. becomes a pain to read an maintain. Option 2. means that code that is currently fairly well-written and makes a lot of sense together will need to be pulled in two or more parts. Option 3. seems very much like an anti-pattern, as this makes it hard to see what dependencies any module has. And in option 4., calling conventions for existing functions change across the board.

Note: initially I worried about option 3. that any code in the body of the module would be executed on every import; however, it was pointed out by @a_guest that "modules are cached (in `sys.modules`) and will be fetched from this cache when needed, not executing the module's code again"

I'm inclined to use option 5. in this case and rewrite `pack\sub_b\b_func.py` like so:

```
def initialise():
    global fa
    from pack import fa as pack_fa
    fa = pack_fa


def fb():
    return 0


def fba():
    return fa()
```

Update `pack\sub_b\__init__.py`:

```
from .b_func import fb, fba, initialise
```

And then `pack\__init__.py` becomes:

```
from .sub_a import fa, fab
from .sub_b import fb, fba

for module in [sub_a, sub_b]:
    if hasattr(module, 'initialise'):
        module.initialise()
```

This gets around the problem by completing all the imports before actually calling the function that closes the loop - which doesn't cause a conflict because there is no actual loop inside the functions.

The downside here is that the `__init__.py` of pack now is aware of the need for initialisation of the `sub_b` module and that module itself has some extra code that is only there as a workaround to this problem, but all the other code works exactly as expected (both new and legacy).

And as long as anyone importing `sub_b` will always call `initialise` at least once before using its content, it can even still be used outside of `pack`, assuming the right dependencies are available.

My question then: **is there a sixth, possibly even better option to deal with circular imports?**

*Note: please, I am not looking for opinions on what is nicer, although if you have a strong, rational argument for why one of these options **must** be considered superior, it might answer my question - but I'm really after a better option I'm just missing here. I'm not making a case for this type of code design - it should have been avoided, but it wasn't.*

*Disclaimer: I'm aware of other questions on SO about circular dependencies and circular imports in Python, but I don't think my question duplicates them, as none of them gets this deep into the woods and asks the final question*

Comment: You should revise the idea of a "pack" that imports a module and is used by that module at the same time. Convenience imports should be there as an external API and not be used by the package itself. Use the original call.

Comment: You should go for option 3, put the import where it is needed. This tampers very little with module structure and removes the circular import in a natural way (while retaining the circular dependency structure). Your concern that the modules' code is executed over and over again is not relevant since modules are cached (in `sys.modules`) and will be fetched from this cache when needed, not executing the module's code again.

Comment: @KlausD. thanks, that does make some sense, but doesn't that mean that each module importing the call from another module needs to know where exactly it resides? Some of these modules are reused in other 'packs' and if they were ever to have their internal structure change, this would affect all the imports in other packs where people would want to reuse them. I understand that this is a bit of a fringe issue, but I'm curious for your response. Would a change to `from ..sub_a import fa` match what you are saying? (in `b_func.py`)

Comment: @KlausD. - apart from liking your comment (it does improve things), it does not actually solve the problem of having circular references though; do you have suggestions for that as well?

Comment: Although you described the problem in general but can you provide details about roles of submodules: a) each one have value by itself, b) main-extensions-addons-etc, c) main and support modules for e.g. testing. I don't think it's possible to just say "Go for option X!" without such info

Comment: @AlexYu I'm not really looking for advice on which option to take, unless there are some general technical arguments (like what `a_guest` suggested). I'm mainly asking if there is a general pattern for solving circular imports that don't come down to "don't create circular imports". In my current situation, the various modules have roles like logging, configuration file processing, basic data cleanup, etc. As an example, the configuration file module may want to log, while the logging depends on configuration data - I know how to refactor this, but the question is how to avoid that if need be.